# How to use threadDelay inside a runContextT

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm currently learning Haskell. (With GPipe)

I have the following code which is part of a program that draws a triangle on the screen:

```
drawyRun :: IO ()
drawyRun = do
  runContextT GLFW.newContext (ContextFormatColor RGB8) $ do
    threadDelay 10
    vertexBuffer :: Buffer os (B4 Float, B3 Float) <- newBuffer 3
    writeBuffer vertexBuffer 0 [ (V4 (-1) 1 0 1, V3 1 0 0)
                               , (V4 0 (-1) 0 1, V3 0 1 0)
                               , (V4 1 1 0 1,  V3 0 0 1)
                               ]

    shader <- compileShader mainShader

    loop vertexBuffer shader 0.0
```

That line `threadDelay 10` is giving compler erros:

```
Couldn't match type ‘IO’
                     with ‘ContextT GLFW.GLFWWindow os (ContextFormat RGBFloat ()) IO’
      Expected type: ContextT
                       GLFW.GLFWWindow os (ContextFormat RGBFloat ()) IO ()
        Actual type: IO ()
```

How do I cause a brief delay inside that runContextT?

Comment: Do you try to use `liftIO . threadDelay $ 10`?

Comment: read up on `monad transformers`. you need to learn about this topic to understand how you can `lift` actions from one monadic context (e.g. `IO`) into another, more specific context (here, something like `ContextT GLFW.GLFWWindow os (ContextFormat RGBFloat ()) IO`). `lift` is the core concept you need to grasp. `liftIO` is basically a convenience fn that will perform the correct number of `lift`s to get from the part of the monad transformer stack that can perform `IO` to the desired layer.

Comment: Aha... I knew I needed to do something with lifting, but I never realized I needed to compose liftIO with threadDelay. Thanks a lot for the help.